# How can I make the Bluemix VCAP_ID cookie secure?

Tags: security, cookies, ibm-cloud

Bluemix generates a VCAP_ID cookie which is not secure at the moment (see below). Is there a way I can force it to be secure? Is there any reason for not making it secure?

Set-Cookie:**VCAP_ID**=[redacted]; Path=/; HttpOnly

vs.

Set-Cookie:**VCAP_ID**=[redacted]; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure

Comment: Could you expand on the "not secure" comment? VCAP_ID is used by the internal router to help send clients to the same app instance when using sticky sessions.

Comment: update: [gorouter#99](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/99#issuecomment-163720027) had been resolved and released in [cf-release v227](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/releases/tag/v227#routing) so now you should be able to get a secure `VCAP_ID` cookie when setting `JSESSIONID` cookie secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is set internally by Bluemix.  We can take this back to the dev team to make the cookie secure though.

Comment: I didn't see this cookie from my blumeix apps anymore.

Answer (score 1):

### What is __VCAP_ID_ cookie

Here's what I found from section [HTTP Sessions Not Persisted or Replicated](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#sessions) of cloudfoundry document:

> Cloud Foundry supports session affinity or sticky sessions for incoming HTTP requests to applications if a jsessionid cookie is used. If multiple instances of an application are running on Cloud Foundry, all requests from a given client will be routed to the same application instance. This allows application containers and frameworks to store session data specific to each user session.

And this sticky session is tracked via a cookie named **`__VCAP_ID_`**, see [cloudfoundry/gorouter/proxy/proxy.go](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/blob/25eb46f7cfe22c56a512b9f17b97bea914073da4/proxy/proxy.go#L24)

### Setup __VCAP_ID_ cookie

checkout [cloudfoundry/gorouter/proxy/setupStickySession()](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/blob/25eb46f7cfe22c56a512b9f17b97bea914073da4/proxy/proxy.go#L344)
The configuration for setting this cookie is a private method which means it's decided internally within proxy. The only variable part are `maxAge` and `Path` which means it uses maxAge/Path of `JSESSIONID` cookie for `__VCAP_ID_` cookie.

I'm curious why `Secure` is not part of this. Instead, it is decided when creating proxy in gorouter. I've create [issue 99](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/99) to track this because it should be as secure as `JSESSIONID`.

Comment: The cookie has been replaced with `X-Cf-Requestid`

Comment: @JeffSloyer I just reproduced that `__VCAP_ID_` cookie is still there in both runtime and latest gorouter code base. are you talking about `X-Cf-Requestid` will be used instead of `__VCAP_ID_` for tracking sticky session?